# Copy git repository to another project locally

Tags: git

Let's say I have project on
`c:/project/project1` and `c:/project/project2`

And then I create another project `c:/project/project3`

```
Assume short form of the word
BR = Branch
RB = Rebase
CP = Copy
[All word & letter inside this [] refer to branch name]
```

Let say `project1` has the following commit that has been rebase

```
INIT--p11---------------------RB BR A--[MASTER]
     \--p12--p13--p14 [BR A] /       \--p15-- [BR B]
```

And Let say `project2` has the following commit that has been rebase

```
INIT--p20--------------------RB BR C-----------------RB BR D--p24--[MASTER]
         \--p21--p22 [BR C] /       \--p23-- [BR D] /
```

My question is:

How do I copy the repository on `BR A` and `BR D` only or maybe with some commit `p24` to `project3` with their files (changed / newly created)

The way I hope in `project3`, the copy branch from another repository should not go to master but on individual branch, then later on to be merge with master and rebasing. I illustrate the structure above on `project3`

```
INIT-----------------------------RB BR A--p31--p32--RB BR D--p24--[MASTER]
    \--p12--p13--p14 [CP BR A]--/                  /
     \--p23 [CP BR D]-----------------------------/
```

I've see guide on how to copy/move/clone repository to another from remote/online repo. But I don't found any relate to local repo.

Comment: You are at the local master branch(master) when you rebase the branch (lets say BR A)?? One more question where did you rebase the BR B? Sorry I just want to understand your question.

Comment: Generally, you init project3, add project1 and 2 remotes, and then merge, cherry-pick, and rebase as you need. However, you're explaining how you'd like to solve your problem. What are you trying to solve? How are projects 1, 2 and 3 related?

Answer (score 0):

**Project 1 Case**

Initially, you have clone one project in this `c:/project/project1` directory. At this stage when you do `git status` it will show that you are on branch master and your branch is up to date with `origin/master`.

Now according to your setup, `BR A` is a branch that keeps track of `origin/master` and it has 5 commits(in your case) which means that `BR A` is 5 commits ahead of origin master. Git will suggest that you need to push this branch to origin/master in order to have a remote repository up-to date.

Here you need to understand one situation, in your local repo you will have two branches one is `master` and another is `BR A`. You are on `Br A` that keeps track of `origin/master`. As branch A has 5 commits ahead of origin/master so you will push it in the remote repository.

After pushing it into the remote repository `git push origin branchA`, in your remote repository you will have two branches one branchA and master.

```
Branch tree in remote
 |--- branchA (5 commits ahead)
 |--- master
```

```
Branch tree in local
 |--- branchA (5 commits ahead)
 |--- master
```

As per your setup, you are at the local master branch and you have rebased the local branch BR A into your master branch `git rebase branchA`. After you did rebase,

```
Branch tree in local
 |--- branchA (0 commits ahead)
 |--- master(5 commits ahead of origin/master)
```

If you want to update your remote master branch then you will do a pull request and once it is approved you will merge it.

```
Branch tree in remote
 |--- master (up to date)
 |--- branchA (0 commits ahead)
```

Now here local remote will looks like this

```
Branch tree in local
 |--- branchA (0 commits ahead)
 |--- master(5 commits ahead of origin/master)
```

Now you will do `git fetch` then your local will looks exactly the same as the remote repository.

```
Branch tree in local
 |--- master (up to date)
 |--- branchA (0 commits ahead)
```

**Project 2 Case**

Similarly, you have initially clone another project in this `c:/project/project2` directory. You did the same exact setup which you did for project 1 but this time you have `branchC` and `branchD`.
After rebasing process in the local and merging process in the remote,

```
Branch tree in local
 |--- master (up to date)
 |--- branchD (0 commits behind)
 |--- branchC (0 commits behind)
```

Now finally the question is you want to have branchA (which is master branch of project 1 actually) and branchB(master branch of project 2) into your third repository **locally**.

> Don't create another repository just merge one repository with another repository.

For that, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10548919/13847690) would help you to achieve what you really want.